# The right way to draw a slashbox without content in a table?

Tags: tables

Here is a part of my table:

```
\begin{table*}[t]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|l|l|X|X|X|X|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Application}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{Version}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{MD5}&\multicolumn{4}{c|}{Result}\\
    \hline
    Anguanjia: Security Manager&4.5.1&adcfd8a30f6b2ae48e8bb44b05589533&35&X&Y&$\blacksquare$\\
        ...
```

And here is what it turned to be:
[image: My Table]

I want to use `\slashbox` to indicate that this cell does not need to be filled, how do I fix this or use a better way to express?

Comment: `\slashbox` produces suboptimal results. I'd suggest you to use other approach and instead od using a diagonal line to indicate that some cell does not need to be filled, use an em-dash (`---`); if clarification is required about the meaning of this symbol, you can add it in a note at the bottom of the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\slashbox` produces suboptimal results; additionally, the idea of a diagonal line in a cell is to have text above and be­low the line to la­bel the col­umn and row that the cell is in. This can be almost always (if not always) presented in a different way reorganizing the table so that no diagonal lines are needed.

I'd suggest you to use other approach and instead of using a diagonal line to indicate that some cell does not need to be filled, use an em-dash (`---`); if clarification is required about the meaning of this symbol, you can add it in a note at the bottom of the table.

I'd also like to suggest you (this, of course, is a personal opinion) not to use vertical rules in your tables and to use the features provided by the [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package. A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ l l l X X X X }
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Application} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Version} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{MD5} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Result} \\
\midrule
Anguanjia: Security Manager & 4.5.1 & adcfd8a30f6b2ae48e8bb44b05589533
  & 35 & X & Y & $\blacksquare$ \\
Anguanjia: Security Manager & 4.5.1 & adcfd8a30f6b2ae48e8bb44b05589533
  & O & V & --- & $\emptyset$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]